# How to access default hyperledger fabric-ca database

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have hyperledger fabric "First Network" up and running in Vagrant on Window 7. I would like to query on following tables of fabric ca database:

- Affiliations
- Users
- Certificates

Kindly help me how and where I can find fabric ca database,

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using version 1.1, you can use the **fabric-ca-client affiliation list** and **fabric-ca-client identity list** commands to see the affiliations and users table, respectively.  The ability to list the certificates will be in a future version of the fabric-ca-client.

By default, the **fabric-ca-server** uses SQLITE and the name of the database file is **fabric-ca-server.db** in the home directory of the fabric-ca-server.  You can use the **sqlite3 fabric-ca-server.db** command to enter a sqlite shell, and then issue **select * from users** to list the users table for example.

Comment: Thank You Keith, 

I installed sqlite3 within my vagrant ubuntu environment. I could able to go to sqllite3 shell, but getting following exception:

Error: unable to open database "fabric-ca-server.db": unable to open database file

Comment: fabric server is configure to use mysql. when i tried to enroll a user, then get server response as : 
Failed to get user: : scode: 404, code: 63, msg: Failed to get User: sql: no rows in result set". how can set to which table to be quueried??

Answer (score 2):

You need to login to the docker container to run sqlite3 fabric-ca-server.db. Follow these steps:

```
$ docker ps
```

find your Fabric-ca container name from the response. Then issue this command:

```
 $ sudo docker exec -it <your-ca>  /bin/bash
```

After logging in, change directories:

```
 root@c6cc601b0360:/# cd ca 
 root@c6cc601b0360:/ca#
```

Then connect to the database:

```
root@c6cc601b0360:/ca# sqlite3 fabric-ca-server.db
```

Run a test query:

```
root@c6cc601b0360:/ca# select * from users
```

Answer (score 1):

it is very simple, just install and run SQL client, for me; I installed SQuirreL SQL client, you need to install the JDBC jar file for SQLite from this [link](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads/):

Then connect to Hyperledger fabric CA DB by setting the path file name [image]

connect to the database then, without username\password if you keep default values, you will see the requested tables as shown below
[image]

I hope I could help.